# Google Chrome: save OR open dialog?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Whenever I click on a pdf (or uimage) on Google Chrome, I get a "save as" dialog box (assuming I set the option to save [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/974948/open-pdf-links-in-external-application-on-chrome/1243004)). I would rather have a dialog with two options, "save as" or "open with", like with firefox (see image below).

Is it possible to have these two options with Google Chrome? I am using version 90.

[image]

Comment: I just right click on the document and get Open, or Save As.  I do not use any plugins to disable the inline viewer, but right-clicking avoids that.

Comment: But that will only open in the internal browser, right? Furthermore for some links this will anyway trigger the _save_ dialog, even if you click on _open_!?

Comment: The right click works in Chrome. I do not open the document in line first.

Answer (score -1):

In Settings, You and Google, toggle advanced. In the downloads section, ensure the "Ask where to save each file before downloading" is turned on. This will effectively give you a "save as" dialog box, allowing you to select location and filename for each saved download. It will also allow you to keep the default filename and will also remember the previous download location.

Comment: But that "save as" dialog won't have the "open with" option, as in the picture I showed, right?